# Why do examples show reload=true for loading language files?

Tags: language, translation

Nearly every example I've seen, both in [documentation](https://docs.joomla.org/Loading_extra_language_files) and code examples, show setting the `$reload` parameter to `\Joomla\CMS\Language\Language->load()` method as `true` (e.g. forcing reload of the language file). Anyone have an insight into why this is the normal practice? It seems to me it's an expensive decision if the file's already loaded.

I'm kind of going crazy in a component I'm writing with how Joomla! handles language `.ini` files. PHP 7+'s `opcache` will not cache non-PHP files. I'd prefer to break all of my language files up into small files: one for the core component strings, one for each view, one for exceptions, and the like. But the overhead of all those files reads is insane.

My solution is to monkey-patch the `Language` object set by `Factory` using reflection in a plugin's `onBeforeInitialise` method, so that it handles both PHP and `.ini` translation files. The only translation file loaded by that point is `en-GB.lib_joomla.ini`, so I'm truncating that file in a plugin catching the installer update event after transforming it to a different PHP file.

I'm similarly using an event in a plugin to catch all extension installs and updates, and transform their language files to PHP in the template language override folder. The speed-up is huge for the complex site I'm working on. (I understand well issues with overriding core, it's not a plugin I'll release on JED).

I haven't looked to see if there's any plans for Joomla! v4 to change how the translation system works.